# How to verify if an embedded field changed on before_save?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am running Ruby 2.1 and Mongoid 5.0 (no Rails).

I want to track on a `before_save` callback whether or not an embedded field has changed.

I can use the `document.attribute_changed?` or `document.changed` methods to check normal fields, but somehow these don't work on relations (embed_one, has_one, etc).

Is there a way of detecting these changes before saving the document?

My model is something like this

```
class Company
   include Mongoid::Document
   include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

   field   :name,    type: String
   #...

   embeds_one :address, class_name: 'Address', inverse_of: :address
   #...

   before_save :activate_flags
   def activate_flags 
      if self.changes.include? 'address'
         #self.changes never includes "address"
      end

      if self.address_changed?
         #This throws an exception
      end
   end
```

One example of how I save my document is:

```
#...
company.address = AddressUtilities.parse address
company.save
#After this, the callback is triggered, but self.changes is empty...
#...
```

I have read the documentation and Google the hell out of it, but I can't find a solution?

I have found [this gem](https://github.com/versative/mongoid_relations_dirty_tracking), but it's old and doesn't work with the newer versions of Mongoid. I want to check if there is another way of doing it before considering on trying to fix/pull request the gem...

Answer (score -1):

Adding these two methods to your Model and calling `get_embedded_document_changes` should provide you an hash with the changes to all its embedded documents:

```
def get_embedded_document_changes
  data = {}

  relations.each do |name, relation|
    next unless [:embeds_one, :embeds_many].include? relation.macro.to_sym

    # only if changes are present
    child = send(name.to_sym)
    next unless child
    next if child.previous_changes.empty?

    child_data = get_previous_changes_for_model(child)
    data[name] = child_data
  end

  data
end

def get_previous_changes_for_model(model)
  data = {}
  model.previous_changes.each do |key, change|
    data[key] = {:from => change[0], :to => change[1]}
  end
  data
end
```

[ source: https://gist.github.com/derickbailey/1049304 ]